# Why the code doesn't click in the button?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to open a IE window and click in the button to automate a repetitive work. The code opens the window but don't click in the button, any help?

The button have this code:

```html
<a tabindex="0" title="Criar Solicitação de Manutenção" 
  class="urLnkReportGl20 urTxtEmph" id="WD54" 
  style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" 
  ondragstart="var e=window.event;e.cancelBubble=true;e.returnValue=false;return false;"
   href="javascript:void(0);" shape="" ti="0" 
  lsevents="{Activate:[{ResponseData:'delta',ClientAction:'submit'},{}]}" 
  lsdata="{0:'Criar\x20Solicita\xe7\xe3o\x20de\x20Manuten\xe7\xe3o',1:'CRIAR\x20SOLICITA\xc7\xc3O\x20DE\x20MANUTEN\xc7\xc3O',4:true}" 
  ct="LN"
<img align="absMiddle" ondrag="return false" 
   alt="Criar Solicitação de Manutenção" src="http://dest-pb0l03.sap.global.*****:8000/sap/public/bc/WebIcons/ur/default/l/Pictogram/Caliper.gif" border="0"</img> CRIAR SOLICITAÇÃO DE MANUTENÇÃO
</a>
```

The code I'm using is this:

```vb
Sub VbaInternet()

Set Internet = New InternetExplorer
Internet.navigate "http://dest-pb0l03.sap.global.*****:8000/sap/bc/webdynpro/sap/zpm_portal?sap-language=PT"
Internet.Visible = True

While Internet.Busy
    Do While Internet.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until Internet.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until
Wend

Dim oElement As Object 'Objeto referente a um Elemento
Dim oElementCol As Object 'Coleção de um tipo de Elemento


Set oElementCol = Internet.document.getElementsByTagName("a")


  'Ao encontrar, é simulado o Click e força a saída do laço.
  If oElement.className Like "urLnkReportGl20 urTxtEmph" Then

  oElement.Click

End If
  Next oElement
End Sub
```

i expect i can click in this button

Comment: You're not looping over `oElementCol`.  However, since the link has an id you can just use `Set oElement = Internet.document.getElementById("a"): oElement.Click`

Comment: Fixed typo:  `Set oElement = Internet.document.getElementById("WD54"): oElement.Click`

Comment: Thank you Tim but, when I try to use getElementsById I got the following error: "438 Object doesn’t support this property or method". I don't know why.

Comment: There is no `getElementsById` method - it's `getElementById` (because it's intended only to return a single element)

Comment: Yeah I know that, I wrote this wrong, sorry. Even using getElementById I got the same error

Comment: If you put a break on `Set oElement = ...` and wait a few seconds before continuing, does it then work?  Might be a timing problem.

Comment: Hmm I didn't try that, I'll try to do it tomorrow and tell if it works. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you Tim, I added the break time line, after that the code's working good!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this with a standard page load wait and let me know the error code you get back if any?

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub ClickButton()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "yourURL"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.getElementById("WD54").Click

        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?